# svm predict always give me the higher label value

Tags: c++, r, svm, vision, lbph-algorithm

here is my code:

```
    int num_files = 2;

    sad = sad.reshape(0, 1);
    happy = happy.reshape(0, 1);

    Mat trainData(num_files, happy.cols, CV_32FC1);
    happy.copyTo(trainData.rowRange(0, 1));
    sad.copyTo(trainData.rowRange(1, 2));

    trainData.convertTo(trainData,CV_32FC1);

    Mat labelsMat(num_files ,1 ,CV_32FC1);
    labelsMat.rowRange(0, 1).setTo(1);
    labelsMat.rowRange(1, 2).setTo(-1);

    labelsMat.convertTo(labelsMat ,CV_32FC1);

    CvSVMParams params;
    params.svm_type = SVM::C_SVC;
    params.kernel_type = SVM::RBF;
    params.term_crit = TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, (int)1e7, 1e-6);

    CvSVM svm;
    svm.train(trainData, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), params);

    Mat testData = elbp;

    testData =testData.reshape(0,1); 

    testData.convertTo(testData ,CV_32FC1);

    float response = svm.predict(testData);
```

sorry im totally a nub here.
i am trying to classify happy and sad face by svm after convert face image to the lbp.
But the predict result is always the higher label, if i label happy 1 and sad -1, it gives me 1 all the time, but if i label happy 1 and sad 2, it gives my 2.
i guess there is some thing wrong with the label or params, or i need to change the way i train lbp to train histogram.
plz help me and give me some advise.
thank you so much.

Comment: You misspelled 'noob'. Seriously though, your really ought to try to capitalize proper pronouns and use apostrophes in contractions if you want to be taken seriously. This does NOT look like R code. And ... even more important in being taken seriously would involve posting a reproducible example which if this is R,  would involve  code to load any packages with a `library()` call..

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? (I'm experiencing the same issue). @42-, it's quite clearly C++ code (as tagged), not sure why r is also tagged, however.